# How to determine what application is sporadically sending tcp/udp traffic (peerblock) via state changes?

Tags: tcp

I use peerblock (which isn't the best, but it's something).

Anyways.  When I'm not downloading anything.  Peerblock activity drops to almost non existent, but occasionally I will see something pop up sporadically.

Now this is key to the question.

I know I can use a tool like tcpview from sysinternals, but I don't want to constantly monitor traffic and generate pages of logs to sift through.

Is there a way to establish a state change baseline and then identify stuff that pops up that isn't normal?  For example I have a VM and HP was blocked on a 192.x.x.x ip on udp port.

But peerblock doesn't tell me what application it was.

So what would be the best way to identify what application it was when I return to the computer many hours later?

Comment: Wireshark, maybe?

Comment: You could try third party firewall tools that allow you to create rules per program. That way you can chose to block everything and 'ask on first connection'. That way when a certain application or process generates outbound traffic, you will be notified and asked if you wish to allow traffic from said app/process. I remember zonealarm in the day used to work like that.

Comment: I remember zonealarm.  I thought it was cool until I had to deal with the popups.